# How to display music information in a jtable and make the jtable clickable to play the song?

Tags: java

```
FileNameExtensionFilter ff=new FileNameExtensionFilter("mp3 files",

"mp3", "mpeg3");

 JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

  fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(ff);

 fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

 int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);

 if (returnVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

    File file[] = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles(); 
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)
    home_player.jTable1.getModel();


    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        Vector v = new Vector();
        int num = dtm.getRowCount()+1; 
        String name = file[i].getName();
        String album = file[i].getParentFile().getParentFile().getName();
        String  art=   file[i].getParentFile().getName();

        v.add(num);
        v.add(name);
        v.add(art);
        v.add(album);
        dtm.addRow(v);
        playerp p = new playerp();
        p.stop();
       }      
     return Arrays.asList(file);

     }

 return null;

}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i am  already able to display the music but having problem implementing the mouse click on the jtable to play the music and also using the next and previous button don`t work although i am using the playlist position to add one to it for next and take one from it for previous but nothing works been up all night trying to figure this out any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to format your code block inside a block-quote? I edited the same for you but you seem to have reverted back to block-quotes.

Comment: You're asking us how to correctly implement a click on a table, and the code you show us is completely unrelated code, constructing a table model. Show us the **relevant code**. And explain precisely what you expect your code to do and what it doesn instead.

Comment: that is the code i use to choose the file path and add them to the jTable. my question is how can you make it clickable to play the path on that row.

Answer (score 0):

You add a `MouseListener` to the `JTable`. If you don't know how to do that then read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Then the code to handle the `mousePressed()` event might be something like:

```
if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
{
    JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
    int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
    int viewColumn = convertColumnIndexToView(1)

    String name = table.getValueAt(row, viewColumn);
    // invoke your music player using the name?
}
```

Comment: @alex, What doesn't work? The MouseListener? Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Again, the SSCCE should only demonstrate the concept. We don't have access to music files. So the mousePressed(...) code will just display the filename for the row clicked. This will prove the MouseListener works. Then it is up to you to add the logic to play the file.